# All emails come to Gmail users as spam

Tags: gmail, amazon-ses, spam, email-spam

my AWS account (I use AWS SES to send emails) was recently hacked and used for spam. I managed to fix the issue, but right now I can not send any emails to users who have Gmail accounts, they all go to spam.
I contacted AWS support, but they recommended contacting Gmail to ask them to unlock your account.
When I contacted Gmail they asked me to contact AWS. I am stuck now in an infinite loop.
I thought it was a typical use case and it should be possible to contact any providers to prove that your account is not longer used for spam or it should be done automatically at all.

I think there must be also an algorithm on Google's side that automatically decides whether an email is used for spam or not, but it probably takes time to validate my email again, not sure. But, anyway, is there a way to solve this issue? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to explain that the resolution for this concern is a gradual process wherein you'll need to make your domain trusted on Gmail's server once more if you've been able to send emails to them before.

Now, you're actually correct in this statement:

> I think there must be also an algorithm on Google's side that automatically decides whether an email is used for spam or not, but it probably takes time to validate my email again, not sure.

One of the things that Google is checking is a [domain's reputation](https://mailmodo.com/guides/domain-reputation/). From the looks of it, that got impacted when the issue happened. I would recommend checking this article out if you have not done so yet. [Prevent mail to Gmail users from being blocked or sent to spam](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126). Things like adding SPF and DKIM for your domain would help out in this matter. *Note: DMARC is an optional DNS record but I would recommend that you also add it because of what happened.*

You can use things like the [Postmaster Tools](https://postmaster.google.com/managedomains) of Google ([Get started with Postmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9981691)) or [MxToolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/) to check the status of your domain and make sure that your DNS records on it are set up correctly.

### UPDATE

If you are looking for an immediate fix now, what I can recommend is to have your recipients that use Gmail whitelist your domain using filters. [Create rules to filter your emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579#zippy=%2Cimport-a-filter%2Cexport-a-filter). To make it easier for them, you can give them an exported filter that has your domain or email address set to "Never send it to Spam" for them to import.

I hope this information helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes, I did everything you mentioned, but it is still blocked

Comment: I've updated my answer with a recommendation that you can have your recipients do in order to make sure that your emails are not sent to spam on their end.

To expand on my previous answer, it would take time for Google's server to trust your domain once again and the information I provided is to help you in the long run.

If you've just added SPF, DKIM, and DMARC to your domain, take into consideration that they will need time to kick in on the system. Based on my experience, it may take up to 72 hours depending on your host.